# Installing Ananconda on Ubuntu 20.04, many erros

Tags: 20.04, anaconda, numpy, conda

Disclaimer: I'm very very  new to Linux.

Background: I'm having issues installing Anaconda on my Ubuntu 20.04. I am running this off of my USB stick on a PC. I tried downloading the community pycharm but it did not work with creating a new folder and getting the panda and numpy packages, and a whole bunch of errors came up when trying to open and work on a .py file. I need a good IDE for python because I am in a Data Science program and I need to be able to open the .py files that are assigned to me and complete the tasks which often includes working with a lot of the anaconda packages.

The Issue:
I cant open the anaconda download after downloading it ,and the sha terminal command [sha256sum /path/filename]does not open and I cant verify the sha data integrity.

Those are just the first few steps and I'm sure I'll run into errors further in the installation as well.

Thank you for your time to whomever reads this!

~Thank you Linas for your help , I cant see the response anymore, I think it got deleted, but your answer through the terminal worked perfectly! thanks again!